# RowGroup function not working when there are multiple datatable to be displayed

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, dt

I have a requirement to show 2 datatables in 2 different tabs in a shiny application. One is a simple datatable whereas the other uses the rowgroup extension of DT package. When I'm using tabs to display both the datatables, the rowgroup function doesnt seem to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(width = "100%", 
             tabPanel("Table 1",
                      fluidRow(
                        column(12, withSpinner(DTOutput("my_table2",height="600px")))
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Table 2",
                      fluidRow(
                        column(12, withSpinner(DTOutput("my_table1",height="600px")))
                      )
             )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$my_table1<-DT::renderDataTable({

    datatable(mtcars[1:15,1:5],
              extensions = 'RowGroup', 
              options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc=c(3)),
                             pageLength = 20),
              callback = JS("
                                $('#DataTables_Table_0 tbody').on('click', 'tr.group', function () {
                                    var rowsCollapse = $(this).nextUntil('.group');
                                    $(rowsCollapse).toggleClass('hidden');
                                 });"))
  })

  output$my_table2<-DT::renderDataTable({

    datatable(mtcars[1:15,1:5],rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(
                order=list(list(1,'asc'),list(2,'asc')),
                scrollX = TRUE,
                pageLength = 100,
                lengthMenu = c(10, 20, 100),
                searching = TRUE)) %>%
      formatStyle(0, target= 'row',color = 'black', backgroundColor = 'silver',
                  fontWeight ='normal', lineHeight='100%')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But if I display the datatable with rowgroup in 1st tab, its working fine. But my requirement is to display the table with rowgroup in Tab 2.

Can someone please help

Comment: Currently `output$my_table_1` maps to the second tab while `output$my_table_2` maps to the first tab. Was this intentional?

Comment: Yes. the requirement is to show the table with rowgroup (my_table1) in second tab while the basic raw DT (my_table2) in first tab. I altered the code to show my_table1 in first tab and my_table2 in second tab which is working fine with the expand/collapse option but not the other way round.